# MongoDB C# driver crash on First() call

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver, mongodb-query

I am having issues with the latest MongoDB C# driver (v1.4.2.4500) crashing when I query this document:

```
{
  "_id" : "4fdfe705b48c6b24dcab994a",
  "CreatedDate" : new Date("6/18/2012 19:42:13"),
  "UpdatedDate" : new Date("6/18/2012 19:42:13"),
  "SiteId" : "4fdfe705b48c6b24dcab9939",
  "ClientId" : "4fdfe705b48c6b24dcab9937",
  "Account" : {
    "UserName" : "blah",
    "Password" : null,
    "PasswordSalt" : null,
  },
  "FbAccount" : {
    "_id" : "838331911",
    "access_token" : "…..",
    "Pages" : []
  }
}
```

Query:

```
var q1 = from u in this.Repository.All<User>()
         where u.FbAccount.Id == "832631911"
         select u;

var foo1 = q1.First();
```

Repository:

```
public IQueryable<T> All<T>() where T : class, new()
{
    return this.GetQuery<T>().FindAll().AsQueryable();
}
```

Exception:

> ```
> [NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
>    lambda_method(Closure , User ) +137
>    System.Linq.WhereEnumerableIterator`1.MoveNext() +155
>    System.Linq.Enumerable.First(IEnumerable`1 source) +244
>    lambda_method(Closure ) +322
>    System.Linq.Queryable.First(IQueryable`1 source) +382
>    Framework.Services.ClientService.GetByFacebookUserId(String
> ```
>
> fbUserId) in ClientService.cs:39

Am I doing something wrong or is this a bug?

Comment: Also filed as a jira with mongodb at https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/CSHARP-502 where a discussion is already occuring.

Comment: Why don't you add your answer so I can accept it? Thanks!